# How do i send my location coordinates via sms in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone please guide me how to send the longitude and latitude of your phone via text message to another phone number? In which format do I enter the phone number, local or International.

Here is my code, permission is already in the manifest:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from new_activity.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        getLocation();
    }
    void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();

                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lati)).setText("Latitude: " + latti);
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Longi)).setText("Longitude: " + longi);
                try {
                    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    String message;
                    String telNumber;
                    telNumber = "XXXXXXXXXX";
                    // Get the string
                    message = "[AUTOMATIC MESSAGE]\n" + "I am currently at \n"+"Latitude" + latti +
                            "and \n"+"Longitude" + longi + " (approximately; accuracy within 100 meters).";
                    manager.sendTextMessage(telNumber, null, message, null, null);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {

                }
            }else {
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Lati)).setText("Unable to find correct location.");
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.longi)).setText("Unable to find correct location. ");
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                    getLocation();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what error are you getting? You need to ask runtime permissions also. Only adding in manifest is not enough

Comment: Arahasya it doesn't  give any error. It just doesn't send the sms.

Answer (score 0):

The telephone number must be

> tel: phone number